# Vaadin: second scrollbar appearing seemingly randomly in AppLayout

Tags: vaadin

My application is using a `com.vaadin.flow.component.applayout.AppLayout` with a header and a drawer (a standard layout inspired by misc. example programs). The lower right content part is populated with VerticalLayouts that have a `@Route(value="foobar", layout = MainLayout.class)` annotation, so when clicking on one of the "anchors" in the drawer the corresponding view is added.

That works all nice except for one thing that annoys me:

One of my views has four Accordion components (2 containing a couple of labels and a TextArea each, one containing some textfields and a chart. The forth contains some text fields and a button).

When I unfold these accordions then typically when expanding the third or fourth there is suddenly a second vertical scrollbar appearing just inside the outer, normal scrollbar. Already two opened accordions are higher than what fits a typical browser window, but here the size and the scrollbar is adjusted correctly. Sometimes, but strange enough not always, the scrollbar also adjusts properly with three opened accordions. Sometimes already with the 3rd, but definitely always with the 4th accordion that second scrollbar appears. The combination of opened accordions does not seem to play a role, i.e. there is no accordion that ALWAYS triggers that scrollbar appearing.

I find this second scrollbar most irritating and annoying when navigating the page. Any idea what could cause this? And how to force a single scrollbar only?

BTW: I experimented with wrapping the entire content inside a `Div` but that didn't change anything - the second scrollbar still appears as described above.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and a code snippet? It’s otherwise very hard to figure out where the problem might be.

Comment: This sounds similar to my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67539336/align-items-list-of-a-select-component.  I'll be interested to see if you get an answer to this.

Comment: It looks indeed similar but I am using completely different widgets. 
What I noticed is: the inner scrollbar correctly represents the *entire* page. The outer one represents the height right *before* the inner one appeared. I.e. its height and "visible fraction" corresponds to the page's height and visible part thereof as it is *before* I open then 3rd, or 4th, resp., Accordion. 
Hope I could make myself clear.